# Exportar PDF API

Tags: api, pdf, descarga

Estoy haciendo una API de facturación y una de las funciones es descargar la factura mediante un PDF, se me otorga el siguiente código:

```
$pdf = $facturapi->Invoices->download_pdf("6238e4a200690b002d5f6d21");
```

pero mi pregunta es, como hago para que la variable se active para que realize la descarga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que devolver el contenido de la variable, especificando en las cabeceras de HTML el tipo de fichero y demás datos.

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```php
$pdfDowload = $facturapi->Invoices->download_pdf($idfactura); // stream containing the PDF and XML as a ZIP file or
#
$file = 'invoice.pdf';
file_put_contents($file, $pdfDowload);
#
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Realiza tu respuesta en formato código, y trata que los comentarios sean español, para qué tu código sea legible y entendible por quién realiza la pregunta. Puedes revisar esta página de ayuda sobre "¿Como responder?" Link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió, solo que ademas de descarga tambien se descarga en el servidor, sabes que opción quitar o poner para que solo se descargue en la PC?